# Module requests not found in dataflow runner

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am building a pipeline on dataflow that sends recieved messages from pubsub, transforms them by making an api call and then writes them to big query.

Writing from pubsub to  bigquery without the api call works perfectly fine. However when i try to use the requests library it always gives me the following error:

```
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined [while running 'CustomParse-ptransform-11727']

passed through:
==>
    dist_proc/dax/workflow/worker/fnapi_service.cc:631
generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 581, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1368, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "PubSub2BQ.py", line 43, in process
```

here is the relevant code:

```py
import argparse
import json
import requests
import os
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions


class MtToJson(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, message):
        x = requests.post('serverAdress', data=message)
        yield x.text

def run():
    # Parsing arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."',
        default=INPUT_SUBSCRIPTION,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table", help="Output BigQuery Table", default=BIGQUERY_TABLE
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_schema",
        help="Output BigQuery Schema in text format",
        default=BIGQUERY_SCHEMA,
    )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    # Creating pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    # Defining our pipeline and its steps
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "ReadFromPubSub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription, timestamp_attribute=None )
            | "CustomParse" >> beam.ParDo(MtToJson())
            | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                known_args.output_table,
                schema=known_args.output_schema,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            )
        )
```

Server adress omited.

I verified that requests is intalled on gcp and it is for python 2.7 and 3.7.

i am running the dataflow runner with requirements.txt that includes the requests module but it does not seem that its getting installed.

EDIT:

I changed the version of the apache sdk to a lower version:

requirements.txt

```
requests>=2.20.1
apache-beam[gcp]==2.25.0
```

and am getting the new huge error message:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache', '-r', './requirements.txt', '--exists-action', 'i', '--no-binary', ':all:']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

 Pip install failed for package: -r
 Output from execution of subprocess: b'Collecting requests>=2.20.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/requests-2.25.1.tar.gz\nCollecting httplib2>=0.17.2\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/httplib2-0.19.1.tar.gz\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status \'done\'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status \'done\'\n    Preparing wheel metadata: started\n    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status \'done\'\nCollecting apache-beam[gcp]==2.25.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/apache-beam-2.25.0.zip\nCollecting certifi>=2017.4.17\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/certifi-2021.5.30.tar.gz\nCollecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/chardet-4.0.0.tar.gz\nCollecting idna<3,>=2.5\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/idna-2.10.tar.gz\nCollecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/urllib3-1.26.5.tar.gz\nCollecting pyparsing<3,>=2.4.2\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/pyparsing-2.4.7.tar.gz\nCollecting crcmod<2.0,>=1.7\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/crcmod-1.7.tar.gz\nCollecting dill<0.3.2,>=0.3.1.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/dill-0.3.1.1.tar.gz\nCollecting fastavro<2,>=0.21.4\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/fastavro-1.4.1.tar.gz\nCollecting future<1.0.0,>=0.18.2\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/future-0.18.2.tar.gz\nCollecting grpcio<2,>=1.29.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/grpcio-1.38.0.tar.gz\nCollecting hdfs<3.0.0,>=2.1.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/hdfs-2.6.0.tar.gz\nCollecting mock<3.0.0,>=1.0.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/mock-2.0.0.tar.gz\nCollecting numpy<2,>=1.14.3\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/numpy-1.20.3.zip\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: still running...\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status \'done\'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status \'done\'\n    Preparing wheel metadata: started\n    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status \'done\'\nCollecting oauth2client<5,>=2.0.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/oauth2client-4.1.3.tar.gz\nCollecting protobuf<4,>=3.12.2\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/protobuf-3.17.3.tar.gz\nCollecting pydot<2,>=1.2.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/pydot-1.4.2.tar.gz\nCollecting pymongo<4.0.0,>=3.8.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/pymongo-3.11.4.tar.gz\nCollecting python-dateutil<3,>=2.8.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/python-dateutil-2.8.1.tar.gz\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status \'done\'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status \'done\'\n    Preparing wheel metadata: started\n    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status \'done\'\nCollecting pytz>=2018.3\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/pytz-2021.1.tar.gz\nCollecting typing-extensions<3.8.0,>=3.7.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/typing_extensions-3.7.4.3.tar.gz\nCollecting avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz\nCollecting pyarrow<0.18.0,>=0.15.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/pyarrow-0.17.1.tar.gz\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: still running...\n  Installing build dependencies: still running...\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status \'done\'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status \'done\'\n    Preparing wheel metadata: started\n    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status \'done\'\nCollecting cachetools<5,>=3.1.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/cachetools-4.2.2.tar.gz\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status \'done\'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status \'done\'\n    Preparing wheel metadata: started\n    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status \'done\'\nCollecting google-apitools<0.5.32,>=0.5.31\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/google-apitools-0.5.31.tar.gz\nCollecting google-auth<2,>=1.18.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/google-auth-1.30.2.tar.gz\nCollecting google-cloud-bigquery<2,>=1.6.0\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/google-cloud-bigquery-1.28.0.tar.gz\nCollecting google-cloud-bigtable<2,>=0.31.1\n  File was already downloaded /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache/google-cloud-bigtable-
```

It seems that it wants to download a bunch of packages that i long removed from the requirements file. Is there a way to clear the cache?

Comment: According to [Dataflow's worker dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies), the requests module should already be installed in the worker. Are you using the same version as listed in that page (2.24.0)?

Comment: @DanielOliveira on gcp web i see its running 2.29.0

Comment: That's probably the Apache Beam version you're describing, since Requests only seems to go up to 2.25.1 right now. I was wondering what version you specified in the requirements.txt. Actually, it might be more helpful if you could include the contents of your requirements.txt in the question, if you can.

Comment: I updated the question since now im getting something different